# Need something like a pointer to a JTable (Java)

Tags: java, pointers, reference, jtable

I have multiple JTables, and I want to create an array where it stores:

a) An index

b) A "pointer" to a certain JTable. I'm used to solving it this way from C++, but I'm new to Java.

Basically, instead of having an array of indeces for JTable1, one for JTable2, JTable3, and so on (since there will be a lot of these tables), I want to have just one big map linking an index to a JTable. I don't see how I could do this without pointers.

Comment: Any variable referencing an Object in Java is essentially a pointer.

Comment: Read this link:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value, it will clarify your doubt.

Comment: Your "something like a pointer" is called a reference.  In Java, all variables of object type store a reference, rather than an actual object.  So a variable of type `JTable` is exactly the "something like a pointer" that you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to have a map like below :-

```
Map<String, JTable> jTableMap=new HashMap<String, JTable>();
```

In above code, key is the name of JTable and value is corresponding JTable instance.

> Java is by pass by value, so no need of any pointers.

Comment: My question may have been a bit unclear, but this does work as a solution as well. What I meant was that I wanted an array of integers/JTables (with the integer not acting as a unique key). However, I can solve that by creating such a map, and then creating a 2d array of integers, where the second integer will be used to look up what array the first belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a pointer. Java uses references. Just store a reference.

In C++, you use the pointer because you don't want to hold a copy of the object. This is unnecessary in Java.